# JDBC - Move cursor out of insertRow

Tags: java, jdbc

I was inserting multiple rows in a ResultSet as shown like below, I need to print out the ResultSet after inserting all rows, so tried moving the cursor back to before first row and it fails there with an error - "Error at this line: Java.lang.IllegalStateException: This method cannot be called when the cursor is on the insert row"

```
ResultSet rs = ...;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
 rs.moveToInsertRow();
    rs.updateString("NAME", "Jon");
    rs.updateString("ADDRESS", "111 New York");
    rs.updateString("EMAIL", "test@test.com");
}

rs.beforeFirst(); // Error at this line: Java.lang.IllegalStateException: This method cannot be called when the cursor is on the insert row

//ResultSet print logic goes here
if( rs.getType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY){
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
         String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
         sb.append(rsmd.getColumnName(i)).append(" : ").append(columnValue).append("      ");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea, how to move the cursor back to initial position when moveToInsertRow() has been invoked?

Answer (score 0):

You should make your Statement scrollable to do this, something like below

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

After having done an insert, you need to leave the insert row using [`moveToCurrentRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#moveToCurrentRow--) to go back to the row you where on, after having done that (and assuming you actually have a scrollable cursor) you can call `beforeFirst()`.

Note that - depending on the driver implementation - it is entirely possible that the rows inserted through the result set are not visible to the current result set.